# Mutual Information: Calculation example (Java) in contingency table style

Tags: java, associations, frequency, corpus

I am using the pointwise mutual information (PMI) association measure to calculate how frequently words co-occure by using word-frequencies obtained from a large corpus.

I am calculating PMI via the classical formulae of

```
log(P(X,Y) / (P(X)*P(Y))
```

and using the contingency table notation with joint- and marginal frequencies I found on http://collocations.de/AM/index.html

The results I get are very similar, but not the same. As far as I understood things both methods should result in the exact same result value.
I made a little Java-programm (minimal working example) that uses word-frequencies from a corpus using both formulae. I get different results for the two methods. Does someone know why ?

```
public class MutualInformation
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long N = 1024908267229L;

        // mutual information = log(P(X,Y) / P(X) * P(Y))
        double XandY = (double) 1210738 / N;
        double X = (double) 67360790 / N;
        double Y = (double) 1871676 / N;

        System.out.println(Math.log(XandY / (X * Y)) / Math.log(10));
        System.out.println("------");

        // contingency table notation as on www.collocations.de
        long o11 = 1210738;
        long o12 = 67360790;
        long o21 = 1871676;
        long c1 = o11 + o21;
        long r1 = o11 + o12;
        double e11 = ((double) r1 * c1 / N);
        double frac = (double) o11 / e11;
        System.out.println(Math.log(frac) / Math.log(10));
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ` very similar, but not the same` BTW I might have written `e11 = r1 * c1 / (double) N; frac = o11 / e11;` and `Y = 1871676.0 / N`

Comment: I get these results:
3.9930973261888347
------
3.768700373995412

similar but not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let write it in the same terms

```
   long o11 = 1210738;
   long o12 = 67360790;
   long o21 = 1871676;
   long N = 1024908267229L
```

The first equation is

```
   XandY = o11 / N;
   X = o12 / N;
   Y = o21 / N;
```

so

```
  XandY / (X * Y)
```

is

```
 (o11 / N) / (o12 / N * o21 / N)
```

or

```
 o11 * N / (o12 * o21)
```

Note there is no adding going on.

The second equation is rather different.

```
c1 = o11 + o21;
r1 = o11 + o12;
e11 = ((double) r1 * c1 / N);
frac = (double) o11 / e11;
```

so

```
e11 = (o11 + o21) * (o11 + o12) /N;
frac = (o11 * N) / (o11^2 + o11 * o12 + o21 * o11 + o21 * o12);
```

I would expect these to be different as mathematically they are not the same.

I suggest you write what you want as maths first, and then find the most efficient way of coding it.

Comment: ok thank you. So it was a misjudgment from me to expect both formulae to result in the exact same result.
I couldn't find a statement regarding the equality of them or why they would differ only a little bit. At least for the case of word-frequencies the contingency table version seems to be used frequently.

Comment: @toobee they actually differ a lot if you don't take the log 10 of them first ;)